# How to approach this map UI functionality with Leaflet? Grid of rectangles for displaying data where zooming in increases the resolution of the grid

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

I want to have a grid over the Leaflet map where intensity of a static scalar value based on the events inside each rectangular cell is shown primarily using opacity and coloring of the cell. (It's not exactly what I'm doing but, for an example of how I want it to work visually: Compared to a cell containing no events, a cell with a greater number of events might have a more opaque white overlay on top of the map covering the bounds of that cell.)

When the user zooms in/out I want the resolution to change, i.e. zooming in means each visible cell covers a smaller geographical area and zooming out means each cell covers a larger area.

I'm very much a newbie to Leaflet and I'm stuck on how to approach the problem. Is there a plugin that can do this? Or else how would I go about constructing the grid layer myself?